# Display Tutorials Based On Tutorial Date and Specified Timezone in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, pagination, timezone, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Please help. I'm working on a site that debut at specific date and time. Tutorials are being displayed to every students on date set on each tutorials. However, I want the tutorials to debut not just by the date and time set on each tutorials but also based on the timezone set on each tutorial. For example, if a tutorial is set to debut today at 8:00pm Eastern Standard Time (EST) of the United States, it should debut at that time instead of debuting at the application set timezone.

I wrote the below code using Laravel collection filter() which seems to do the trick. However, the page is taking longer to load and I'm unable to use laravel paginate(). I need to use Laravel paginate() to reduce the number of records being pulled at once. There are over four thousand tutorials. Please help.

```
// upcoming tutorials
$tutorials = Tutorial::orderBy('id', 'desc)->paginate(20);
$futureTuts = $tutorials->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    $today = new \DateTime('now');
    $show_date = new \DateTime($value->show_date, new \DateTimeZone($value->timezones->name));
    return $show_date > $today;
});

$upcoming_tuts = $futureTuts->all();
```

Please any solutions around this to be able to use Laravel default paginate(). I believe using Laravel pagination will cause the page to load faster. I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Thanks

Comment: i really can't understand your language but seems i can help you i am giving you 2 suggestion as answer

Comment: @sid-heart, How can I integrate so that also check for the timezone set on each tutorial? Right now, it's only comparing Today's date against the published_at date. What we want to do is to check if Carbon::now() is equal to published_at time and the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

try to use datatable can filter your data from database as api
here is package
yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
and if you want to use as published try something different like this
add a column as published_at

```
  $table->dateTime('published_at');
```

than in your model define your table

```
 protected $dates = ['published_at'];

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){

        $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    }

    public function scopePublished($query)
    {
        $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function scopeUnpublished($query)
    {
        $query->where('published_at', '>', Carbon::now());
    }

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return $this->asDateTime($date)->toFormattedDateString();
    }
```

now you can use published scope in your controller like this

```
$tutorials = Tutorial::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->published()->paginate(5);
```

Comment: How can I integrate the timezone so that the method is also checking for the timezone set on each tutorial? Right now, it's only comparing Today's date against the published_at date. What we want to do is to check if published_at is greater than Carbon::now() based on time and the timezone.

Comment: The timezone field for each Tutorial is different from the published_at date field. That's why I'm asking.